# WP User Avatar Front End Update Avatar

Tags: wordpress

I'm Using the https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/ plugin,
but I'm on a little problem, I need to update my user image on /my-account/edit-account/ link, on my site. This code show the for, allows to me upload or select a image but on update information, it doesn't save. How do I update a new image ?

```
<?php do_action('edit_user_avatar', $user); ?>
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I founded is create a new php file to handle the POST, creating a new form only for the avatar.

I used this code on markup

```
<form class="woocommerce-EditAccountForm" action="upload-avatar.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <?php do_action('edit_user_avatar', $user); ?>
                <button type="submit" class="btn rounded-0">Update Avatar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And for the upload-avatar.php.

```
require_once("../../../wp-load.php");
if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
    update_user_meta(wp_get_current_user()->id, "wp_user_avatar", $_POST['wp-user-avatar']);
} else {
    $upload = wp_upload_bits( $_FILES['wpua-file']['name'], null, file_get_contents( $_FILES['wpua-file']['tmp_name'] ) );
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $upload['file'] ), null );
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $attachment = array(
        'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['baseurl'] . _wp_relative_upload_path( $upload['file'] ),
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $upload['file'] )),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload['file']);
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $upload['file'] );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    update_user_meta(wp_get_current_user()->id, "wp_user_avatar", $attach_id);
}
wp_redirect('/my-account/edit-account/');
exit;
```

I've used a different handle for the admin, because this role can access the media library.

Comment: This upload code is working for manual upload of file. Worked for me for custom file upload.